# WPF MVVM DataGrid ItemsSource binding to different collection

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, datagrid

I have a Window with a dynamic menu and a DataGrid that shows different records based on the which menu item has been clicked.
Each menu item returns an ObservableCollection of a custom class.
All the classes are diffent and not necessarily related to each other.

At the moment I created one ObservableCollection(Of Object) in my ViewModel, filling it with new results everytime a menu item is clicked.
The problem is that Object does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged, forcing me to manually assign the ItemsSource.

I'm sure there is a way to accomplish what I'm after, but I cannot think of it.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- clear the ObservableCollection, then add the new items to it. This can be slow though as there are multiple notifications (events) fired when you do it, if it's any more than a few tens of items then you'll start to notice some UI slow downs while you do it
- ensure that your viewmodel implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and the property that contains the ObservableCollection fires a property change notification. Then simply assign a new ObservableCollection when you have a new list to show.

Because your collections contain different types of objects, I trust you've looked into [Data Templating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview) ([another example](https://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html)) to structure your UI - that way you can have a custom layout that is dependent on the type of the list item.

Comment: I actually have multiple collections, but each one of them contains items of the same type. Also, my ViewModel already implements the INotifyPropertyChanged, but is I use an ObservableCollection(Of Object) it will not fire the PropertyChanged event even when I add a new item to the collection.

Comment: @FabioL.The ObservableCollection implements [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) which means it **does** notify when an item is added or removed. You haven't included any code so I have to presume you've correctly got a notification being fired from the setter of the VM property containing the ObservableCollection. It doesn't make any difference what types of objects are in the collection. Maybe you could add more details to your question for a more accurate answer?

Comment: After a lot of thinking, I ended up using an IEnumerable as a source for the DataGrid. This way I was able to directly assign every collection without having to manually add every single item. I'm still not completely satisfied with how things work, but for the moment it works ok. In the future I will try to find a way to improve the logic behind the Window. Thanks for your help!